# Unable to understand Casting difference in Userdefined classes and standerd classes in java

Tags: java

I have searched for this still have a confusion in mind.

**Below is example of Casting of Standered Class**

```
public class Q {
  public static void main(String... str){
    Number b = 10;
    Integer i = (Integer)b; // Workes Fine
  }           
}
```

**Below is example of Casting of user defined Class**

```
class H{}

class I extends H{}

public class Q extends I{
   public static void main(String... str){
     I i = (I)new H(); //Show runtime java.lang.ClassCastException
   }           
}
```

Above is the example of inheritance. Such that :

1. Integer Extends Number
2. I Extends H

**Why Integer i = (Integer)b works and I i = (I)new H() not?**

Comment: Here is a nice little tutorial to help you understand what you are trying to do: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50451-upcasting-downcasting/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `new H()` creates an object of class `H` which is neither `I` nor `I`'s **subclass** so it can't be cast to `I`.

While `Number` `b` in the first example **is** an `Integer`  - there is implicit `new Integer(10)` there (`Number` is an abstract class), so it can obviously can be cast to `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Number b = 10;
Integer i = (Integer)b; // Workes Fine
```

In this case you are telling java compiler trust me b is an integer(at runtime) and it actually is(10 is an integer).

BUT

```
I i = (I)new H(); //Show runtime java.lang.ClassCastException
```

You are telling compiler H is I which is not true(Same as Animal is not dog).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `I` in `new H()` so  You need to create I then only you can cast.

Try this one.

```
   H h = new I();
   I i = (I)h;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why Integer i = (Integer)b works

This works fine because the statement `Number b = 10;` is implicitly converted to `Number b = new Integer(10);` Hence the above casting works fine.

If you want to test this, just try out the code below:

```
Number n = 12342444444; // Wont compile: Expects the literal to in the range of int
Integer i = (Integer) n;
```

**By default the value assigned to Number reference is treated as of type int.**
The above code will compile if you assign the value as long.

```
Number n = 12342444444L; // Will compile
Integer i = (Integer) n; // ClassCastExcpetion: Cannot cast Long to Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Number b = 10; is the same as Number b = new Integer(10)  Integer is a subclass of Number. While in your example H is not a subclass of I